# Splitting a string on a certain point

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, split

I'm trying to split a string on certain points (multiple points) so for example

```
string = "AAATTTCCCGGGAAATTTCCCGGGAAATTTCCCGGG"
```

split on TC[1] (need to get this from a dict can be anything else), and end up with

```
list = ['AAATTT','CCCGGGAAATTT','CCCGGGAAATTT','CCCGGG']
```

I now just use split but it loses the TC but i need to keep them.

The splitting point is a variable but this is a small example.

Comment: share what u have tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

In your specific case, replace what you want and introduce another delimiter to split on, eg:

```
>>> text = "AAATTTCCCGGGAAATTTCCCGGGAAATTTCCCGGG"
>>> text.replace('TC', 'T\tC').split('\t')
['AAATTT', 'CCCGGGAAATTT', 'CCCGGGAAATTT', 'CCCGGG']
```

Expanded for multiple variables to split options:

```
import re

text = 'AAATTTCCCGGGAAATTTCCCGGGAAATTTCCCGGG'
replacements = {
    'TC': 'T\tC',
    'CG': '\tCG'
}
rx = re.compile('|'.join(re.escape(el) for el in sorted(replacements, key=len, reverse=True)))
res = rx.sub(lambda m: replacements[m.group()], text).split('\t')
# ['AAATTT', 'CC', 'CGGGAAATTT', 'CC', 'CGGGAAATTT', 'CC', 'CGGG']
```

Comment: wont work the TC can be something different aswell and i need to be able to use it for multiple variables i need to get a value from a dict (in this case the TC) and check if it is in the string and then split it on that point of the string

Comment: @NathanWeesie might want to improve your question then with examples of that... but sounds like you can just iterate over that `dict` for what you want to search for, with a key that's the replacement text, then do the same as above.